# in R Replace values with following value

Tags: r

I have a data set that I'm cleaning. The 2nd column starts with a - while the value below it is the one I need. How do I replace the - with the value under it.

I have thousands of rows like this, with the value below it being different names so I cant just do

df$agent[df$agen == "-"] <- "john"

It would have to be done over 1,000 times. I'm looking for a way to do this much more efficiently.

```
1   Field Support   -       6:00 AM - 6:59 AM   1/1/2020    9   
3   Field Support   John    7:00 AM - 7:59 AM   1/1/2020    4   
4   Field Support   John    8:00 AM - 8:59 AM   1/1/2020    4
```

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a reproducible question as suggested here- https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example include your data (as a dataframe object or use dput("yourdata"), the code you have tried and your expected output. This will make it more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case_when` and `lead` from the `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(Name = case_when(Name == "-" ~ lead(Name),
                          TRUE ~ Name))
           Role Name              Time     Date Value
1 Field Support John 6:00 AM - 6:59 AM 1/1/2020     9
2 Field Support John 7:00 AM - 7:59 AM 1/1/2020     4
3 Field Support John 8:00 AM - 8:59 AM 1/1/2020     4
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Role = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Field Support", class = "factor"), 
    Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("-", "John"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(1:3, .Label = c("6:00 AM - 6:59 AM", "7:00 AM - 7:59 AM", 
    "8:00 AM - 8:59 AM"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = "1/1/2020", class = "factor"), Value = c(9L, 
    4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with base R and package `tidyr`.

```
library(tidyr)

col_num <- 3
is.na(df[[col_num]]) <- df[[col_num]] == '-'
fill(df, all_of(col_num), .direction = "up")
#  V1            V2   V3                V4       V5 V6
#1  1 Field Support John 6:00 AM - 6:59 AM 1/1/2020  9
#2  3 Field Support John 7:00 AM - 7:59 AM 1/1/2020  4
#3  4 Field Support John 8:00 AM - 8:59 AM 1/1/2020  4
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "
1   'Field Support'   -       '6:00 AM - 6:59 AM'   1/1/2020    9   
3   'Field Support'   John    '7:00 AM - 7:59 AM'   1/1/2020    4   
4   'Field Support'   John    '8:00 AM - 8:59 AM'   1/1/2020    4
")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without using any packages:

```
> df <- data.frame("ID" = c(1, 3, 4, 5, 8), 
                  "Job" = rep("Field Support", 5), 
                  "Agent" = c("-", rep("John", 2), "-", "Mary"), 
                  "Hours" = c("6:00 AM - 6:59 AM", 
                              "7:00 AM - 7:59 AM", 
                              "8:00 AM - 8:59 AM", 
                              "9:00 AM - 9:59 AM", 
                              "10:00 AM - 10:59 AM"), 
                  "Date" = rep("1/1/2020", 5), 
                  "Metric" = c(9, 4, 4, 6, 2))
> print(df)
  ID           Job Agent               Hours     Date Metric
1  1 Field Support     -   6:00 AM - 6:59 AM 1/1/2020      9
2  3 Field Support  John   7:00 AM - 7:59 AM 1/1/2020      4
3  4 Field Support  John   8:00 AM - 8:59 AM 1/1/2020      4
4  5 Field Support     -   9:00 AM - 9:59 AM 1/1/2020      6
5  8 Field Support  Mary 10:00 AM - 10:59 AM 1/1/2020      2

> df$Agent[which(df$Agent == "-")] <- df$Agent[which(df$Agent == "-") + 1]

> print(df)
  ID           Job Agent               Hours     Date Metric
1  1 Field Support  John   6:00 AM - 6:59 AM 1/1/2020      9
2  3 Field Support  John   7:00 AM - 7:59 AM 1/1/2020      4
3  4 Field Support  John   8:00 AM - 8:59 AM 1/1/2020      4
4  5 Field Support  Mary   9:00 AM - 9:59 AM 1/1/2020      6
5  8 Field Support  Mary 10:00 AM - 10:59 AM 1/1/2020      2
```